# does long if else if else blocks fall under any design pattern

Tags: c#

for example if have a if else like below , i want to know if this falls under any design patern ,in daily life i come across something like this so many times and don't think its good
to write so many if else blocks

any guidence is really appreciated

sample///

```
 if(dotcom){
  else if (frenc){}
  else if (german){}
  else if (brazil){}
  else if (someothercountry){}
 // and the else if block goes on 
  else {}
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd lean towards the Strategy pattern, here's an example

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/11/22/applying-strategy-pattern-instead-of-using-switch-statements.aspx

Comment: perfect link for what i am alooking , great and thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 2):

You're definitely on to something. If it feels wrong or repetitive, there's probably a better way.

Your example seems like a localization problem. Since you're on .NET, you could take a look at the System.Globalization namespace for some hints at how things like UI localization are handled in an object-oriented way.

The exact pattern to follow instead of if/else for any given situation will depend on what's inside your curly braces -- do different countries have different values of properties like "Population" or "Url Suffix" or "Do I need to apply for a visa before I go There"? Let's assume the latter, which will probably be the case 99% of the time. Basically, if you have something like this:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
    public bool NeedToApplyForAVisaFirst { get; set; }
    public string DefaultWordForClickHere { get; set; }
}
```

Code can go from:

```
if ("france")
{
    button.Text = "French(Fr) for 'Click Here'";
}
else if ("brazil")
{
    button.Text = "Portuguese(Br) for 'Click Here'";
}
.....
```

to:

```
button.Text = User.Country.DefaultWordForClickHere;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a code smell to have too many `switch` statements and `if-else if` like that. There are two possible solutions:

1. You should generally piggyback on virtual method dispatch mechanism offered by your object-oriented language to figure out the code snippet that's going to be executed. You'll need to have a class for each condition, with an `abstract` base class. In each class you'll override a method that customizes the behavior.
2. Use lookup tables (in your specific question, I speculate this to be probably more relevant; this is more useful if you have similar code in all paths but they are going to depend on different values for some variables).

I believe there are legitimate use cases for such kind of blocks and a large object hierarchy is not always worth it.  It's a code smell, not a hard rule.

Comment: @afshari , i don't want you to write the code, but can you provide me some link for virtual method dispatch mechanism example, thanks for your time and help

Comment: @gov: Basically, you'll have an abstract base/interface with a virtual method. In each subclass (that represents a single `if` branch in your current code) you do something specific to that branch by overriding the virtual method. The client code will simply call that method.